# Responsive video banner on Safari has huge gaps top and bottom

Tags: html, html5-video

I'm trying to implement a very simple video as a banner on a website using html5 tags. I just need it to be full width and responsive, which appears to work perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but not Safari.

Here is a simplified version taken from a more complex wordpress page using exactly the same markup and the same happens.
http://noisilyfestival.com/video-test.html

I've set the video background to red, see in Safari there are huge gaps at the top and bottom whereas in Firefox and Chrome it sits flush.

Can't figure out for the life of me what's going on here! I've set the video to display:block which fixes the few pixel gap at the bottom but cannot resolve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hyperlink is broken and please paste code here or create fiddle.

Comment: Damn, sorry about that...hyperlink now works! http://noisilyfestival.com/video-test.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was pointed out to me that on resizing the browser width the issue would correct itself. Therefore the intrinsic ratio technique is the most efficient way to ensure this works cross browser...
http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video

Works as it should now on all browsers I've tested it on.

Answer (score 0):

I removed display:block; from #homepage-video and Safari looked just fine.

Comment: That doesn't work for me! Here it is on my local machine with display:block; removed from #homepage-video. http://prntscr.com/9qyxl0  There's a gap the same height below the video also when you scroll down. Setting a height gets rid of these gaps but obviously this isn't then responsive!

Comment: Safari version 8.0.2 on Macbook btw

Comment: Take display:block off of #homepage-video and then re-upload so I can look at the code. If I inspect that element, and turn off the display:block, everything snaps into place like it should.